# Dialogflow: how to express a list of dictionaries as intent parameter

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a platform in which there are some DB entities.
For simplicity, let's say that I have entities composed by:

- Name Surname (dialogflow type: person)
- Birthday (dialogflow type: date)
- [...]
- *articles* (dialogflow type: ?)

Now, articles is different table with a one to many relationship, and each article it's composed by a *name* and a *value*.

So, a simplified entity with articles, if I express its structure using JSON notation, is something like:

```
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "birthday": "2019-05-12",
  "articles": [
    {"name": "art1", "value": "val1"},
    {"name": "art2", "value": "val2"},
    {"name": "art3", "value": "val3"}
  ]
}
```

Now, the intent is triggered using an **Event** that reads a specific entity from the database and returns a structure like the one just seen.
But I cannot think to a good way to represent the *articles* in the Intent parameters, considering that it should probably be modified and then saved back to the server using a webhook.
Can you please give me some hints?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine multiple values together in a single entity have a look at composite entities. You could use it to capture the key value pair of your articles by using dialogflow entities or your own custom ones.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-developer#developer_composite

To capture them as a list you should check the is list checkbox in your intent.